# Unable to use esprima with ReactJS - Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, esprima

I am trying to parse a functions parameters with esprima in react js. I am getting following error

Error: Line 1: Unexpected token (
▶ 9 stack frames were collapsed.
App.render
src/v4/EsprimaTest.js:12:29
   9 | 
  10 | 
  11 | render() {

> 12 |   const  parsed= esprimaFB.parse(this.sum.toString())
>        |                           ^  13 |   const  parsed1= esprima.parse(this.sum.toString())
>     14 |   return (
>     15 |   
>   View compiled

My source code is as follow. I tried both esprima and esprima-fb

```
import React from "react";
var  esprimaFB = require("esprima-fb");
var  esprima = require("esprima");

class App extends React.Component {
  sum = (a,b)=>{
    return a+b;
}


  render() {
    const  parsed= esprimaFB.parse(this.sum.toString())
    const  parsed1= esprima.parse(this.sum.toString())
    return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(parsed)}</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(parsed1)}</div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by moving sum function outside the class. But does not know why it did not run when it was in class scope.

```
import React from "react";
var  esprimaFB = require("esprima-fb");
var  esprima = require("esprima");

 const sum = (a,b)=>{
    return a+b;
}
class App extends React.Component {



  render() {

    const  parsed= esprima.parse(sum.toString())
    return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(parsed)}</div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use **sum** inside the class, you have an arrow function.

Try to change:

```
esprimaFB.parse(this.sum.toString())
```

To:

```
esprimaFB.parse(this.sum().toString())
```

I don't know if the error you were getting was related to this, give it a try.